# How can I change the visible / hidden property of a button with javascript?

Tags: javascript

On my page I have the following theme change buttons:

```
<button class="small theme" name="darkBlue" onclick="setThemeColor(this)">
   <span style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">#</span>
</button>
<button class="small theme" name="black" onclick="setThemeColor(this)">
   <span style="color:black; font-weight:bold;">#</span>
</button>
```

I have this javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      if (localStorage.themeColor) {
         document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage.themeColor;
      }

      function setThemeColor(button) {
         localStorage.themeColor = button.name;
         document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = button.name;
         var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
         for (var themeButton in themeButtons) {
             themeButtons[themeButton].disabled = false;
         }
        button.disabled = true;
      }
   </script>
```

This always shows the two buttons but I would like to so that instead of the
current button being disabled then the button is not visible. Can someone 
suggest how I could do this?

Comment: `themeButtons[themeButton].style.visibility = 'hidden'`?

Comment: Could I also do button.style.visibility = 'visible'; for the part below that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setThemeColor(button) {
    localStorage.themeColor = button.name;
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = button.name;
    var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
    for (var themeButton in themeButtons) {
        themeButtons[themeButton].disabled = false; // Re-included from original code
        themeButtons[themeButton].style.visibility="visible" // Corrected from original answer
    }
    button.disabled = true;
    button.style.visibility="hidden" // Added/Moved from above after noted I'd messed up the logic
}
```

Comment: But I think your example works the wrong way around. I need the one button to be visible and the other button to become invisible (after I just pressed it or if localstorage is set to that theme).

Comment: I would also need the appropriate button to be hidden if there was a localstorage value for that theme so I could select the other theme.

Comment: Then use Visibility = visible for those which you require visible, and Visibility = hidden for those you wish to hide.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. Are you correct setting visibility?

Comment: My preference is to use the display attribute, display="none"/"block"/"inline" etc., but this has it's own (many) pitfalls. In regards to why it didn't work, I forgot to put the .style part on the visibility line, e.g. button.style.visibility.